# C++/CLI project as static library and different behaviour between VS2013 and VS2015

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++-cli

In an app I'm working on (built with Visual Studio 2015), I have the following structure:

```
Project A -> Native DLL project. This references project B
Project B -> Native static lib project. This references project C.
Project C -> Static lib project with CLR support turned on.
```

`Project A` call a function from `Project B`, which in turn creates an instance of a class from `Project C`. The instantiated class has a member which is a wrapper around a managed object.

The problem I'm facing is that when I build the code in Release mode, once the code tries to instantiate the class from `Project C`, it blows up and says that heap has been corrupted. The place where it blows up seems to be the following function from `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\crt\src\vcruntime\pureMSILcode.cpp`

```
[System::Diagnostics::DebuggerStepThroughAttribute]
_CRT_SECURITYCRITICAL_ATTRIBUTE
int __clrcall _initterm_e (
        _PIFV * pfbegin,
        _PIFV * pfend
        )
{
        int ret = 0;
        /*
         * walk the table of function pointers from the bottom up, until
         * the end is encountered.  Do not skip the first entry.  The initial
         * value of pfbegin points to the first valid entry.  Do not try to
         * execute what pfend points to.  Only entries before pfend are valid.
         */
        while ( pfbegin < pfend && ret == 0)
        {
            /*
             * if current table entry is non-NULL, call thru it.
             */
            if ( *pfbegin != NULL )
                ret = (**pfbegin)();
            ++pfbegin;
        }

        return ret;
}
```

Now here is the thing ... If I turn `Project C` into a DLL (rather than a static lib) everything works fine. What's more interesting is that all this used to work fine when I built the code in Visual Studio 2013. With VS2015, I don't get any heap corruption if I build the code in debug, but it blows up in release.

I'm aware that having CLR support in a static lib is not the best idea, however I can't seem to find any good information about the issues in having CLR support in a static lib. Additionally this was working all fine in VS2013.

I can just change `Project C` to be a DLL (which makes more sense when having CLR support), however I would like to understand what has caused the current settings to blow up when converting to VS2015.

The following is a close representation of the relevant code from each project:

**Project C:**

Foo.h

```
class FooA
{
public:

    FooA();

private:

    struct FooAImpl;

    std::unique_ptr<FooAImpl> _impl;
};
```

Foo.cpp

```
struct FooA::FooAImpl
{
    gcroot<ManagedFoo^> managedFoo;

    FooAImpl(ManagedFoo^ managedFoo_) :
        managedFoo(managedFoo_)
    {
    }
};

FooA::FooA()
{
    _impl = std::unique_ptr<FooAImpl>(new FooAImpl(gcnew ManagedFoo()));
}
```

**Project B:**

FooB.h

```
class FooB
{
public:
    Result GetResult();
};
```

FooB.cpp

```
Result FooB::GetResult()
{   
    FooA fooA;

    Result r = ...;
    return r;
}
```

**Project A**

FooC.h

```
class FooC
{
public:
    void Bar();
private:
    std::unique_ptr<FooB> m_pFooB;
};
```

**FooC.cpp**

```
void FooC::Bar()
{
    Result r = m_pFooB->GetResult();
}
```

Hope someone has some information around what issues may occur in having a static lib with CLR support. Hope the information I provided describes the problem well.

Comment: @Ðаn Yes I already did that and it appears to have fixed the problem (as I already mentioned in the question). However, what I am interested in is finding out why it does not work when the CLR project is a static lib. More specifically, why it did work in VS2013 but not in VS2015.

Comment: @Ðаn The consumer of the CLR project is a native one, not a .NET one. I'm aware .NET does not accept static libs, however in this case I'm not referencing the CLR project in a .NET one. As I said the projects structure worked fine in VS2013.

Comment: This is standard SIOF, the Static Initialization Order Fiasco that C++ code suffers so heavily from.  There is no simple way to determine in which order initialization code gets called, it is a side-effect of link order.  It got a lot worse in VS2015 because of the significant CRT rewrite needed to split-off the "universal runtime".  And nasty with managed code around, very important that native code initialization is done before any managed code runs.  Excessively hard to debug and to fix, if you found a workaround then you kneel down and thank the Merciful Lord.